# How can I remove myself from a Google Search Console property, without intervention from the property owner?

Tags: google-search-console

I was given access to clients' Google Search Console properties while carrying out work for them. How can I now unlink my Google account from their properties, being careful not to remove them entirely? I see only options for `Manage property` and `Delete property` in the dropdown menu for a property.

Comment: When you are "managing" a property do you see the "Users and Property owners" option in the _gear_ menu? "being careful not to remove them" - Assuming you were added as a "user" by the property "owner" then you won't have permission to remove _them_ or anyone else. The question is, can you remove _yourself_ without intervention from the property owner?

Comment: Indeed, edited for clarification. I don't have `Add or remove users` option in the properties I want to leave, but do have it for properties I own e.g. my personal website. Though I do have a `Delete property` option for all of them.

Comment: This may help. Make sure they have an owner user of their own. [Does deleting a property from Google Search Console delete it for all users, or just me?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112778/does-deleting-a-property-from-google-search-console-delete-it-for-all-users-or)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested the following with two different accounts:

**As long as you are not an owner of the property**, you can simply use the `Delete property`-function.

It will remove the property from your list, but not remove your permission to view it, nor your account from the list of `Users and property Owners`. Therefor you are able to re-add the property via the `Add a property`-function.

Regarding the `Users and property Owners`-list. As far as I see, this is only shown to the owner(s). Neither adding a user with restricted or full rights gave them access to that list.

The best way would probably be to tell your client to remove you from the users.